# Delete Key and BackSpace Key Events are not working in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events

I have below code in my react component

```
export default class CalculatedMeasure extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            let formulaInput =  [ 
                            "(", "(", "(", "2", "+", "3", ")", "*", "3", ")", "+", "(", "12", "/" ];
            this.state = {
               formulaArray: formulaInput,
               selectedIndex: size(formulaInput)? size(formulaInput) - 1: 0

             }
           this.handleDeleteCalculatorValues       = this.handleDeleteCalculatorValues.bind(this);
        }
handleDeleteCalculatorValues(event = {}) {
        const { keyCode } = event;  
        let keyPressCodes = [ON_DELETE_KEY_PRESS,ON_BACKSPACE_KEY_PRESS];       
        if (isNil(keyCode) || includes(keyPressCodes,keyCode)) {
            if(isEmpty(this.state.formulaArray)){
                return false;
            } 
            let index = this.state.selectedIndex;       
             if(!isJsonObject(this.state.formulaArray[index]) && !isOp(this.state.formulaArray[index])){
                const newArray = this.state.formulaArray;
                newArray[index] =   this.state.formulaArray[index].slice(0, -1);
                if(newArray[index].length == 0){
                    this.setState({
                        selectedIndex: index - 1
                    })
                }
                this.setState({
                    formulaArray: newArray                  
                }); 
            }            
            else{
                this.state.formulaArray.splice(index);
                this.setState({
                    selectedIndex: index - 1,
                })
            }   
        }
    } 
        render(){
           return()
    <div ref={this.calculatedMeasureRef} tabindex="10" id="calculated-measure-container" className="col-md-12"  onKeyDown={this.handleDeleteCalculatorValues}>
<div>{this.state.formulaArray}</div>
</div>
        } 
}
```

when I'm trying to delete the elements in formula Array using BackSpace key and Delete Key they are working fine in Chrome but those keys are not working as expected in IE.

In IE,when BackSpace Key is pressed,window is moving to previous Tab and sometimes no action is being performed

Comment: You need to return false to prevent the default action of the webbrowser

Comment: even I have tried that but didnt work

Comment: I don't see your `includes()` method. Where is that defined? Or, did you mean `keyPressCodes.includes(keyCode)`?

Comment: I have imported that from loadash

Comment: could you post this script on jsfiddle so we could test ?